# NOIP.com Domainname returns wrong IP via Google DNS

Tags: domain-name

at home I'm using the Noip.com service to set up a domain name for my ip address at home. For this you get a client which refreshes your IP-adress every 5 minutes.

Now I'm using the google dns server for my connections on my windows machine. 
When I'am using nslookup to check my ip adress it always returns 100.101.19.9...

If I check the no ip page the IP-adress show correctly. If I'm using not the google DNS the IP with nslookup is also correct.

Does anyone have a clue what the problem is or how I can figure out why google got the wrong adress?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the IP address of your domain was `100.101.19.9` previously, and Google Public DNS still has that address cached. Google has a [page where you can flush cache entries](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache), which you should try to first to see if it helps. The record you want flushed is RR Type A.

A more detailed answer would be possible if your question mentioned the actual domain name.

Comment: Looks like that clear the Google cache worked for me. Could it be, that however Google got a wrong IP adress with a very big TTL value so their DNS didn't checked for updates?

Comment: @pennertenner That is a plausible explanation, the answers you got from Google Public DNS before flushing the cache should be telling you how much time is left of the TTL. I believe there are DNS providers which will cache for no more than 48 hours regardless of TTL, but I don't know if that is the case for Google Public DNS.